# How to get string value of a List<t> Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have some file paths stored in a List and need to attach them to an email. But how can I access the values (in my case: file paths as string values) of my List Items?

Here is the code:

```
List<string> filesToSend = new List<string>();
filesToSend = (List<string>)Session["filesListForFilesToSend"];

for (int i = 0; i < filesToSend.Count; i++)
        {
            //message.Attachments.Add(filesToSend[i].????????????????????);                
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what does `message.Attachments.Add(...)` take as parameters? Heck, which API is this in the first place? What is `message` here? (because I know of at least 2 APIs that would match that). What is in the array? file names? or actual strings you want sent as text attachments?

Comment: the path to the file in the file system as string I suppose.

Comment: Any reason why you're creating a new instance of `List<string>()` and then immediately overriding the value on the next line?

Comment: I am creating my list an fillìng it with data from my session where this list was filled with data on another page. Anything wrong here?

Comment: As Felipe says in his answer, if you're allocating the list to the variable `filesToSend` you don't need to create an instance of it first - it'll work, but is just unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filesToSend[i] will return the path string you want

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
foreach(string EachString in filesToSend)
{
  message.Attachments.Add(EachString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need to instance a first list the after read the list in session, just:

```
List<string> filesToSend = (List<string>)Session["filesListForFilesToSend"];
```

When you access and `List` by `index` you will get the object of generic type. You can do it using a lot of ways, for sample:

using `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesToSend.Count; i++)
   message.Attachments.Add(filesToSend[i]);
```

or `foreach`

```
foreach(string file in filesToSend)
   message.Attachments.Add(file);
```

or `while`

```
int i = filesToSend.Lenght;
while(i--)
   message.Attachments.Add(filesToSend[i]);
```

I would use `foreach` statement, but `while` will give you more performance (keep in mind you will loop in the reverse order).

Answer (score 0):

The error was not how I was trying to get the string out of my List. The error was how I was trying to attach it to my message.

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesToSend.Count; i++)
        {
            string filePath = filesToSend[i];
            Attachment attached = new Attachment(filePath);
            attached.Name = filePath;
            message.Attachments.Add(attached);
        }
```

Thats the way it works for me. Thank you all